# Start a server using a shell script

Tags: command-line, server, scripts, automation

Now, I need to start the server like this.

```
$./server.start
```

I have to this every time I start and logged into my machine. It would be so good if there is a script which does the same automatically when I again start the machine.

Need help with that.

Comment: What is written in the script? If you have only comands, like `service foo start` or `systemctrl start foo` there is a easy way

Answer (score 0):

After ssh to the server Just backgrounding your script (./myscript &) will not daemonize it. You must disconnect stdin, stdout, and stderr, and make it ignore the hangup signal (SIGHUP).

```
nohup ./myscript 0<&- &>/dev/null
```

will do the job. Or, to capture all output:

```
nohup ./myscript 0<&- &> my.admin.log.file &
```

and, [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-a-simple-bash-script-to-restart-server-programs) article more helpfull for you!